# SQL Query via Python works on local model but not on Database

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm writing a Python function called *get_all_locks()* to get all the elements locked by a certain user.
I'm using the *win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App").Repository* to communicate with EA. The function works well when called on a local EA model (.eapx), but returns no results when used on a Database. The *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers* is used as Database Interface.
Is there anything I need to modify in my query syntax to make it work with the Database too?

This is the function:

```
  def get_all_locks(self, domain, user_login):
    locked_elems = set()
    query = ("select * from t_secuser u where u.UserLogin = '{​0}​\\{​1}​'"
             .format(domain, user_login))
    result = self.rep.SQLQuery(query)
    root = ET.fromstring(result)
    if not list(root):
      print("User not found!")
      return locked_elems
    query = ("select s.EntityID from t_seclocks s inner join t_secuser u "
         "on s.userID = u.userID where u.UserLogin = '{​0}​\\{​1}​'"
         .format(domain, user_login))
    result = self.rep.SQLQuery(query)
    root = ET.fromstring(result)
    for entity in root.iter('EntityID'):
      locked_elems.add(entity.text)
    return locked_elems
```

Using the following SQL query within the EA Query interface works well with the local eapx and with the remote Database:

```
  select s.EntityID from t_seclocks s inner join t_secuser u
  on s.userID = u.userID where u.UserLogin = 'domain\username'
```

Comment: Which database are you using? And what is the exact contents of the query that fails? Does it fail also if you hard code it instead of dynamically filling in the string?

Comment: The Dispatch only opens the running EA instance, no matter which DB is connected. Your code should work on either. I have done so quite often.

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong and posted an answer.
I printed the XML returned by SQLQuery to check if it was actually returning empty, which it was not. The rest is in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what was going wrong here.

The XML that SQLQuery returned on a local (.eapx) model had the tag *EntityID* for ElementGUID, while the XML returned by SQLQuery on the Database had the tag *entityid*. The problem is that *root.iter('Xyz')* is case sensitive so that's why I wasn't getting any results when searching for *EntityID* in the XML returned on the Database.

In my case, I knew exactly what the structure of my XML is going to be, so I modified my code to first see what the tag for ElementGUID is and then search for that using *root.iter()*.

```
result = self.rep.SQLQuery(query)
root = ET.fromstring(result)
guid_tag = root[0][0][0][0].tag
for entity in root.iter(guid_tag):
    locked_elems.add(entity.text)
```

There definitely must be a more robust way to do this, either by converting all the tags to lower/upper case or by searching for *entityid* or *EntityID* instead of indexing it in *root* as I did in *root[0][0][0][0].tag*. But this works for now and I will probably write a better version of this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So an indirect answer to the question you raised in your answer: I use a wrapper class for repository which adds an operation like this:

```
import win32com.client
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Repository:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("EA.App")
            self.eaRep = app.Repository
            models = self.eaRep.models
            done = True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            done = False
        ...

    def query(self, sql):
        root = ET.fromstring(self.eaRep.SQLQuery (sql))
        data = root.getchildren()
        if len(data) == 0: return []
        ds = data[0][0]
        rows = []
        for row in ds:
            cols = []
            for col in row.getchildren(): cols.append(col.text)
            rows.append(cols)
        return rows
```

That allows for

```
for objId, name in rep.query("SELECT object_id, name FROM t_object"):
  print(name)
```

(I do have lots more wrapper operations, of course.)